# Difference between how Visual studio loads assemblies and Assembly.LoadFrom?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an assembly (2 actually) both are from SAP directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui`.

- Visual Studio `Add Reference` - Works just fine.
- `Assembly.LoadFrom` - Throws exception below.

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfewse.ocx' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Why is it that I can add the reference to visual studio and use the dll that way no problem, but loading it via reflection doesn't work?

Is there a way to load the assemblies types at runtime?

Comment: These dlls are used through COM, but `Assembly.LoadFrom` only works for .NET assemblies. The `COMReference` only includes interfaces. Maybe you *should* explain why you are trying to load these dynamically.

Comment: The program we're using only allows GAC assemblies on the server and we need to access assemblies on the client's computer. Additionally the same error is given if we try to add the assembly to the GAC anyways.

Comment: Well, these are native libraries, so you don't need to include them in the GAC. I think you shouldn't even have to distribute them alongside your own assembly (you are embedding the interop types), but I may be wrong here. Just make sure the SAP stuff is installed on the client machine.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429627/dynamically-loading-unmanaged-ocx-in-c-sharp

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. It connected some dots for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lucas pointed out in the comments, `Assembly.LoadFrom` only works on .NET assemblies and the assemblies I was trying to load were COM dlls.

What I ended up having to do was add them to a project which produced Interop versions of the dlls which I then added to the GAC so that the program we originally wanted to use it with could access it.

Thank you to everyone who posted in the comments that lead me to this solution.